# Django sentry default tags

Tags: python, django, sentry, raven

I'm using python-raven to automatically capture all 500 in my django project, and it works great. I'm also forwarding some exceptions that I handle and append them with a special tag to be able to filter them out. The problem is that I can not filter for messages that is missing a particular tag so I'd like to set a default tag for all messages, but can't get it to work.

I've tried the following but it's just ignored.

```
RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'dsn': 'udp://x:y@z:q/w',
    'tags': {'testtag': 'value'},
}
```

Does anyone know how to send a default tag to sentry?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After looking into it a bit more it seems like this is not at all possible ATM.

Answer (score 8):

The following works for me in the settings module.
It adds the environment variable `DJANGO_ENVDIR` to every message being sent.

```
from raven.contrib.django.client import DjangoClient as RavenDjangoClient
class SentryDjangoClient(RavenDjangoClient):
    def build_msg(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super(RavenDjangoClient, self).build_msg(*args, **kwargs)
        data['tags']['ENVDIR'] = os.environ.get('DJANGO_ENVDIR', 'unset')
        return data

if get_env_var('SENTRY_DSN', False):
    RAVEN_CONFIG = {
        'dsn': get_env_var('SENTRY_DSN'),
        # NOTE: timeout set via DSN
    }
    SENTRY_CLIENT = 'project.settings.base.SentryDjangoClient'
```

You need to adjust the SENTRY_CLIENT setting, according to where you put the SentryDjangoClient class, which extends the `build_msg` method.

Comment: If you've been following along in the console you may have seen the `Sending message of length` disappear. Don't worry, just make sure your root logger (or wherever `SentryDjangoClient` lives) log level is set to `DEBUG`.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a different name to the logger, before logging the message. That would allow you to filter by the "logger" in the Sentry server.